# Comparative adverbs

Tags: adverbs, comparatives, morphology, flat-adverbs

"Officially" (or so I believe) English doesn't have comparative adverbs (a single word rather than "more" + an adverb), but *faster* is in common usage as one, for example:

> Do it faster

When strictly speaking one should say:

> Do it more quickly

Is the former an error in grammar? Or has English (d)evolved to such an extent that *faster* may be used as a comparative adverb?

Comment: Wictionary thinks it exists: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/faster

Comment: "More quickly" is still comparative. Also, what do you mean by "officially"? If it's really official, certainly you can provide a dozen sources off the top of your head.

Comment: English hasn't (d)evolved—at least not in this respect; *faster* has been an adverb for over 400 years. Shakespeare: *"I follow'd fast, but faster he did fly;"*

Comment: @RegDwighт Perhaps the questioner means comparatives formed via a morphological ending (-er/-est) rather than analytically (more/most).

Comment: Hard, high, strong, quick. These all have morphological endings. High>>>Higher, though; and then highly>>>>more highly. It sounds like the OP is confusing rules with -ly adverbs and non -ly adverbs.

Comment: The [British Council](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/comparative-adverbs) are happy to have a page devoted to **comparative adverbs**. Okay, so we have to *work **harder*** and *dig **deeper*** to find "single-word" examples, but they're good enough for me. To *dig more deeply* is for the birds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Both adjectives and adverbs inflect by degree in precisely the same way in English. There is no difference between them whatsoever.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, I'm not sure exactly what OP is getting at here, but I'm guessing it's the fact that we don't have forms like ***quicklier***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But we have *early, earlier, earliest* and *late, later, latest*, proving once and for all that adverbs in general suffer no such prohibition. Neither do adjectives; witness *lonely, lonelier, loneliest* and  *comely, comelier, comeliest*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is also the irregular set: “I did it well, he did it better, but she did it best of all.”  Case closed?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know where this myth got started, but adverbs and adjectives form inflections by degree in precisely the same way.  There is no difference at all.

> - They pushed harder, faster, and deeper that day than ever before.
> - Our team worked hardest.
> - Their drill delved deepest.

And it isn’t even the case that there is some rule that somehow exempts  *‑ly* modifiers — be they adjectives or adverbs, it doesn’t matter — from inflections of degree.  They take either *more* or *-er* for comparatives, and either *most* or *‑est* for superlatives.  Watch:

> - I showed up earlier than he did.
> - I got here earliest.
> - He got here later.
> - I have curlier hair than you.
> - One is the loneliest number you’ll ever know.

Also, *onliest* has a long history, although it is now mostly confined to dialect.

And there is absolutely nothing whatsoever with saying:

> - He ran faster than any of us that way.

No one, but no one, can ever say a word against against it.

---

### Edit

Here are more examples of comparative adverbs.

Given that this is an adverbial use:

> A man walks clean if in a foul way he contract but a few spots of dirt.

Can he then not walk cleaner?  Similarly here:

> The riches of the East expended that they might sleep soft and wake in magnificence.

Can they not sleep softer that way?

Consider this laughter:

> I shouted ‘hurrah’, and laughed loud and long.

Can I not laugh louder and longer?

Can a joke that falls flat, if retold, fall flatter?

If one day you’re sitting pretty, and things get even better the next day, couldn’t you be sitting prettier?

Could you not be harder-pressed to do something today than yesterday?

Consider these adverbial uses of *dear*:

> - 1807 Byron Ho. Idleness, To E. N. Long 99 ― The dear-loved peaceful seat.
>     I shall soar higher tomorrow than today.
> - 1822 Scott Pirate xix, ― That knowledge, which was to cost us both so dear. 
>     & 1833 Ht. Martineau Cinnamon & P. vii. 124 ― It must do without some articles··or pay dear for them.

If you paid dear yesterday, and dearer today, and paid dearest tomorrow, those are all normal inflections.

I could go on all day, but surely it is clear by now that there has never been any general “rule” forbidding inflecting adverbs by degree.

(Sure, there are some adverbs that you just don’t do that with, like *now* for example, but that is a wholly different matter.  It is hard to be “nower” simply because *now* does not readily admit inflection by degree.  But even for that one, you could probably put together a situation where it would somehow be understood.)

Comment: Not even unofficially?

Comment: I suppose what it mainly comes down to is *soft*, for example, can be used adverbially just as well as *softly*. So we don't need *softlier* and *softliest* because we've already got *softer* and *softest*. [Ockham's Razor](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question76497.html) and all that. Excellent examples, btw!

Answer (score 1):

"Officially" English does not have comparative endings for adverbs ending in -ly. However, as the comments show, there are plenty of official adverbs that do not end in -ly and actually look like adjectives. These are called [flat adverbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb), and they do have comparative and superlative morphological endings. *Hard, harder, hardest*, for example. They used to be more common, but around the end of the [19th century](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7epnfcHy5SA) grammarians decided it was for the best if we differentiated adverbs by giving them their own suffix (-ly) that does not change in comparative form.

To give you an idea of the increasing rarity of flat adverbs, consider some of these ear-straining uses that were quite common before the 20th century but have have since died out:

- "tottering on his fore feet, for he was *powerful* tired"
- "yet Jonah was *exceeding* glad"
- "And, O, *wondrous* precious blood"

However, don't tell anybody from New England about this or they'll give you a *wicked* hard smack upside the head.

---

In terms of your two examples, depending on what "it" refers to, we might prefer *fast* over *more quickly*.

A person might "drive *faster*" if we were referring to the speedometer, and she might "drive *more quickly*" if we were referring to her knack for finding shortcuts home.

Some hard line prescriptivists might chide you for using "faster" instead of "more quickly" in a case where both could fit, but that's just preference. You have the dictionary on your side. For now. However, there are lots of instances of where a flat adverb will not do and you will need an -ly adverb. For instance,

> I love you deep (no)
>
> I love you deeply (yes)

And the other way around,

> Stand close to me (yes)
>
> Stand closely to me (no)

An easy way to know if an -ly adverb is called for is if the adverb answers the question "how?" As for when it's okay to use a flat adverb, this [site](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/flat-adverbs-are-flat-out-useful/) says "they’re most often suitable for brief imperative sentences."

Hopefully this helps answer your question.

Comment: This is not true.  Both adjectives and adverbs work exactly the same way as far comparatives and superlatives go.

Comment: The article on flat adverbs is useful, but I'm not sure that _kind_ is one and I'm sure it's not in _be kind_.

Comment: @tchrist: I said as much. -ly adverbs don't add a comparative suffix, flat adverbs, which are identical to their adjective form, do. This is the difference between the OPs two examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: In the comments to that article people noted a few mistaken adverbs. I was mainly interested in the claim that flat adverbs are for brief, emphatic sentences. I think we have come to expect -ly adverbs and the flat version sounds terse, making it seem brief and empatic.