# Early vs Earlier usage

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, sentence, comparatives

Which of the following sentences are correct. Early vs earlier. Can I use both sentences?

1. I went on my lunch break late. Next time I will try to take my break earlier.
2. I went on my lunch break late. Next time I will try to take my break early.

Comment: You can use both sentences, but they don't have the same meaning.

Comment: Can you explain why they don't have the same meaning?

Comment: Try grammar book.

Comment: Yes, you can use either sentence pair. However, as nnnnnn pointed out, they have different meanings. The adverbs in example (1.) are **comparative** adverbs, some good examples of which can be found at this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94992/comparative-adverbs.